# Html Canvas transform property issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am building software and one of its functionalities is to highlight a clicked html element. Using a div or another element as an overlay for this functionality works very well, but adds to one of the factors that reduce the speed of the software, so I thought to use an Html canvas instead.

Transformed html elements have their original position and sizes distorted but I found a solution to that. When I try the solution on normal overlays, it works well (you'd see that in the snippet) but on HTML canvas it renders differently which to my point of view doesn't make sense, except the principle behind transforms on canvas is different from CSS transforms(which is just pure math).

If you check the snippet you'd see what's wrong. on none transformed html elements, using canvas works perfectly but on transformed elements it doesn't. The canvas box drawing is black bordered while the div is dotted blue in case you wonder which is which.

You could provide a totally different working code if possible. In the snippet, I use both an overlay and canvas for the html highlighting

```js
const overlay = document.querySelector("#overlay");
const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");


canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


let info = {};
let info1 = {};

document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {    
   const el_info = elementInfo(e.target);
   
   info = el_info;
   info1 = el_info;
   
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
   
   useCanvas();
   useOverlay();
});



        function elementInfo(target) {
          const computed = $style(target);
          const rect = $rect(target);
          const box = {
            target: target,
            width: rect.width,
            height: rect.height,
            offsetW: target.offsetWidth,
            offsetH: target.offsetHeight,
            top: rect.top,
            left: rect.left,
            transform: computed.transform == 'none' ? false : transform(computed.transform),
          };

          function transform(args) {
            args = args.replace(/[^\d|,|\-|\.]/g, '');
            return args.split(',').map(item => parseFloat(item.trim()));
          }

          return box;
        }

        function useCanvas() {
            const trans = info.transform;
            ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

          if (info.transform) {
               calculateAfterTransform();
            ctx.setTransform(trans[0], trans[1], trans[2], trans[3], trans[4], trans[5]);
               ctx.strokeRect(info1.left, info1.top, info1.width, info1.height);
           } else {
             ctx.strokeRect(info.left, info.top, info.width, info.height);
           }
      }

        function useOverlay() {
          setStyles(overlay, info)
          if(info.transform){
            calculateAfterTransform();
            setStyles(overlay, info1);
            const trans = info1.transform;
            overlay.style.transform = `matrix(${trans[0] +","+ trans[1] +","+ trans[2] +","+ trans[3] +","+ trans[4] +","+ trans[5]})`;
          } else overlay.style.transform = 'none';
        }

        function $style(element) {
          return getComputedStyle(element)
        }

        function $rect(element) {
          return element.getBoundingClientRect()
        }

        function setStyles(ele, obj) {
          if (Object.keys(obj).length !== 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
              const key = Object.keys(obj)[i];
              const val = Object.values(obj)[i];
              ele.style[key] = val + 'px';
            }
          }
        }
        
        function calculateAfterTransform() {
        const target = info.target;

        
        const rect = (function rect() {
            var x, y, w, h;
            x = (info.width - info.offsetW) / 2;
            y = (info.height - info.offsetH) / 2;

            x = Math.max(x, -x);
            y = Math.max(y, -y);

            x = info.left + x;
            y = info.top + y;

            w = info.offsetW;
            h = info.offsetH;
            return { left: x, top: y, width: w, height: h }
        }());
       

        info1.left = rect.left;
        info1.top = rect.top;
        info1.width = rect.width;
        info1.height = rect.height;
        
    }
```

```css
canvas {
   position: fixed;
   pointer-events: none;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

#overlay {
  border: 1px dashed blue; 
  position: fixed; 
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.skewed {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 17px 0;
  transform: skew(30deg, 10deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="width: 150px; height: 105px; transform: rotate(50deg); background: red; margin: 100px;"></div>
  <p style="margin-bottom: 10px;">you can see that on none transformed elements, the html canvas works well...</p>
  
  <p class="skewed">But on (some or all) transformed elements it doesn't quite render properly </p> 
  
  <i> Remember canvas drawing is the <b>black bordered box</b> <br>
  while the div element overlay is <b>dotted blue box</b><br>
  <b>Click on the elements to see the overlays </b>
</div>

<div id="overlay"></div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with transforms can be tricky enough in canvas alone. Aligning the canvas draw with an element adds another level of complexity...but not much.

First I would only move the element around by using `translate`. Using margin and left, top, right, bottom will make things even more difficult and don't get accounted for in the transform matrix.

```
<div id="rect" style="width: 150px; height: 100px; transform: translate(100px, 100px)  rotate(65deg) ; background: red;"></div>
```

Second be sure to set the left and top to 0 for the canvas in css as you will need to draw the outline off of it's context. The reason is that using css rotation is default at the center. For canvas it's default is the top-left which means we need to draw the outline at -width/2 and -height/2;

```
ctx.strokeRect(-75, -50, 150, 100);
```

Lastly to get the top-left (0,0) of the canvas in the center of the html element we need to add half the width and height to our translate positions in the matrix

```
ctx.setTransform(
    matrix[0],
    matrix[1],
    matrix[2],
    matrix[3],
    matrix[4] + 75, //Add half width
    matrix[5] + 50 //Add half height
  );
```

Now you should have a properly aligned outline of the element.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const rect = document.getElementById("rect");
let rectBounds = rect.getBoundingClientRect();

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let rectW, rectH, rectL, rectT, rectB, rectR;

document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(rect)
  rectW = parseInt(style.width.replace(/\D/g,''));
  rectH = parseInt(style.height.replace(/\D/g,''));
  rectL = parseInt(style.left.replace(/\D/g,''));
  rectR = parseInt(style.right.replace(/\D/g,''));
  rectT = parseInt(style.top.replace(/\D/g,''));
  rectB = parseInt(style.bottom.replace(/\D/g,''));
  rectMargL = parseInt(style.marginLeft.replace(/\D/g,''));
  rectMargR = parseInt(style.marginRight.replace(/\D/g,''));
  rectMargT = parseInt(style.marginTop.replace(/\D/g,''));
  rectMargB = parseInt(style.marginBottom.replace(/\D/g,''));

  const matrix = style.transform;

  splitMatrix(matrix);
});

function splitMatrix(matrix) {
  matrix = matrix.replace(/[^\d|,|\-|\.]/g, "");
  let matrix2 = matrix.split(",").map((item) => parseFloat(item.trim()));

  drawOverlay(matrix2);
}

function drawOverlay(matrix) {
  console.log(rectMargL)
  ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
  ctx.strokeWidth = 3;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.setTransform(
    matrix[0],
    matrix[1],
    matrix[2],
    matrix[3],
    matrix[4] + rectW/2 + rectL + rectMargL,
    matrix[5] + rectH/2 + rectT + rectMargT
  );
  ctx.strokeRect(-rectW/2 , -rectH/2, rectW, rectH);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.restore();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   pointer-events: none;
}
#rect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 76px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translate(30px, 43px)  rotate(40deg);
  background: red;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rect"></div>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but... remember I said this is for a software... the html element which the canvas draw is aligned to, is not styled by me but the user..  therefore, using the canvas should work under all circumstances.. and also you said: 'The reason is that using css rotation is default at the center. For canvas it's default is the top-left which means we need to draw the outline at -width/2 and -height/2'... I don't get what you mean...  can you give a little more detail??

Comment: The only way I could think of doing that is to account for all styling possibilities and add them to the formula. I updated the snippet to add margin and left and top along with translate and rotate. I'm sure there's uses that will not work like possibly setting both bottom and top or other tings. I can't account for everything here but the idea should be the same.

Comment: As for the rotation point: CSS default transform origin is the center while objects drawn on the canvas are the top-left of the context. So to get a rotation point of a drawn object to appear like it rotating from the center you can draw a rectangles x and y values at negative half of it width and height. There is also another method to translate it, then rotate it, then translate it back right after. I would check of some info on rotation of canvas.

Comment: I just need to know, please did you run my code snippet..??.

Comment: Although thanks for the info on the transform origin... The thought never crossed my mind